# using an `AND` comparison in SQLite selection

Tags: android, sqlite

I really dont know SQL stuff and what you can and cant do but what I am trying to do is do a query on my database for a person/persons.

for example:

I would like to get the list of people that are part of `team A` and that are considered a `substitute` for `team A`

this is what I come up with but I dont know if this is right or not?

```
BowlersDB.TEAM + "=" + teamSelected + "AND" + BowlersDB.SUB + "=1"
```

so again if the person is part of the `teamSelected` and is considered a sub for that team (`1` would mean that they are considered a sub) then I want them listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks fine, but remember to leave spaces in the `" AND "` so it doesn't cause a syntax error. Try it and report back if you still have problems.